# AngularJS foreach loop with JsHint and eq operator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, jshint

I have one error on my JSHint from Grunt and it goes along the lines of:

```
line 48  col 23  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
```

Using '===' breaks the code.

I've Google around and apparently the option to disable this is broken (using latest version as of 4th, September 2014)

My code goes as such:

```
$scope.getStationById = function(stationId)
{
    var parsedId = stationId,
    foundStation;

    angular.forEach($scope.stations, function(station) 
    {
        if(station.id == parsedId)
        {
            foundStation = station;
        }
    });

    return foundStation;
};
```

Any suggestions on how I can silence this annoying error?

**EDIT**

A console log of:

```
console.log(station.id + " | " + parsedId);
```

Produces:

```
1 | 1
3 | 1
5 | 1
```

Comment: Check the type of both operands. They must not be the same.

Comment: add following log statements and tell whats the output, console.log(typeof station.id); console.log(typeof parseId). I think one is String and other is number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the way you're trying to disable it is using `eqeqeq: false` in the options?

What you can try as an alternative is adding

```
// jshint ignore:line
```

At the end of the line

OR

```
/* jshint ignore:start */
...
/* jshint ignore:end */
```

around a block of code, as per the [docs](http://www.jshint.com/docs/).

The best approach is still probably to fix the code so it does not have to rely on type coercion to work. You can use `parseInt(str, 10)` for this.

Comment: The second piece of code works though, multiline block ignore.